# run-time calculations with non-type variadic templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

**Is it possible to make run time calculations with non-type variadic templates?**

Imagine the following situation:

```
template<unsigned int... indexes>
struct s
{
   unsigned int getPosition(const unsigned int target) const;
};

s<2,5,0,7> obj;
std::cout << obj.getPosition(5) << std::endl; //< this should output 1
std::cout << obj.getPosition(2) << std::endl; //< this should output 0
```

The `getPosition` method should return the position of the given integer in the template parameter pack. If the given integer is not present in the parameter pack, an error (preferably at compile time) should be generated.

P.S. I know how to do this if the signature is changed to

```
template<unsigned int... indexes>
struct s
{
   template<unsigned int target>
   unsigned int getPosition() const;
};
```

Unfortunately, this is not an option for me as the method should be virtual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could dump the indexes into a `std::array` and use `std::find`.

```
struct s
{
   unsigned int getPosition(const unsigned int target) const {
       static std::array<int, sizeof...(indexes)> indexArray { indexes... };
       auto pos = std::find(std::begin(indexArray), std::end(indexArray), target);

       if (pos == std::end(indexArray)) {
           //handle error, probably an exception   
       }

       return std::distance(std::begin(indexArray), pos);
   }
};
```

You can't generate a compile-time error if `target` doesn't exist, as you only know `target` at run-time.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Would you have an idea how to modify the solution (or the function signature/design) such that the computation can be done at compile-time. I know that the function will only be called with compile-time constants. But I haven't found a way to express this to the compiler (other than using a template function).

Comment: Mark it `constexpr`? I think you'd need to take the `static` off the array too.

Comment: It seems that `std::find` is not a `constexpr` function.

Comment: You could just do the search in a loop.